# Mongoose unique validation on `findOneAndUpdate` failure

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a User model which username is a unique key which has a custom unique validator. I bumped into a problem that when I want to update a user and `username` is not changed, it gives validation error. Is it good practise to only `$set` things that has been changed when calling `findOneAndUpdate`? If so, I think I have to diff user data before calling `findOneAndUpdate`, which I feel is a little bit too heavy.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'username is required.'],
    trim: true,
    unique: true, // unique index, not unique validation
  },
…
});

this.model.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.params.id },
       {
        $set: {
          username: req.body.username,
          role: req.body.role
        }
      },
        { runValidators: true },
        (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return res.sendStatus(400);
          }
          return res.sendStatus(200);
        }
      )
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the "context" option to "query" as stated in this document: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators

Comment: I'm not sure why you downvoted this? Using the context solves this exact problem, if you want my code example just let me know but I don't think it's necessary, the documentation has it all.